# JMeter CSV reading different values- need to read same values

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have a Jmeter Scenario that is reading ID's from a CSV file ( two headers: SaveKey and SubmittedKey ) On the site that I'm testing

I need to save a report and submit it, *According to process it generates its own unique ID's every time a report is saved and submitted, so those ID's I have, saved in the CSV file.*

However, the save and submit requests in JMeter both are reading different ID's from the CSV files (eg.. save reads 101 and submit reads 102) ; Is there anyway to fix this issue in JMeter?

I also get an error: ReusableResources:txt_WebAPI_YouDoNotHaveThePermission/r/n when I try and run my script

Comment: Right click on the file and change the access to read/write. Instead of writing into csv file, why can't you save the string runtime and pass it along in the subsequent requests.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam because the ID is different at every submit

Comment: Then you need to use Regular Expression Extractor to catch the unique ID and pass it in the subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your problem is related to CSV file reading ; You just follow some steps to solve this issue

- As you said 101 for read and 102 for submit, Make sure for **both variables** should be the same number of values in CSV file and no cell is empty
- You have to check CSV configs, Like Recycle on EOF (should be false in your condition)- Stop thread on EOF(true) - Allow quoted data(False)
- CSV Data Set Config is used to read lines from a file, and split them into variables ; So make sure " , " is selected in csv **delimiter** config
- If your both variables is in same file and these properties is set, then CSV will read accordingly you want in this case.

Hope This Helps !